# EGit clone from and push to GitHub

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit, git-clone

I have an Eclipse (CDT) project setup with EGit to commit to local master and push to github.

So far I have been just using this setup to pretty mush act as cloud backup from my primary dev PC

But now I would like to be able to work on the same project on multiple PC's, but without having to fork the github repo.

I'll tell you now, I have tried several times to understand git further than the very basic basics but have always got lost in the terminology etc.

If I use EGit on the secondary PCs to clone the github repo, should I then be able to simply commit and push any changes there to GitHub as if I was still working on the primary PC, or will I have to pull/rebase/etc each time I need to do new work on either PC?

I think I did *try* to set this up before but ended up with two master repos somehow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out I simply need to CLONE the project to begin with, make any changes the COMMIT and PUSH.

Then on another PC, if I already have a clone, PULL (or FETCH and MERGE) the changes, make any new changes then COMMIT and PUSH again.

This way each local repo has a clone and the user needs to ensure they have the most recent changes pulled from the remote repo before starting adding new changes